# Automatically check available GPU on Google Colab

Tags: pytorch, gpu, google-colaboratory

Is there an automatic way to check which GPU is currently available on Google Colab (Pro).

Say I would like to use a Tesla P100 instead of the Tesla T4 to train my model, is there a way to periodically check with a python script in Colab whether the P100 is available?

I have tried eliminate the kernel periodically but it won't restart again automatically after shutting down:

```
import os

def restart_runtime():
   os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to check what GPU is available. Add the line:

```
!nvidia-smi
```

to the beginning of your code and then keep on disconnecting and reconnecting the runtime until you get the GPU that you want.